# My code isn't enough to show a triangle

Tags: windows, winapi

The codes below is in winmain function after registering a class for the parent window:

```
RECT disrect;
HWND stat = CreateWindow("BUTTON","abcdef",
    WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_OWNERDRAW,10,150,500,100,dis,0,0,0); 
HDC hdc=GetDC (stat);
FillRect(hdc,&disrect,CreateSolidBrush(RGB(3,5,54)));   
SetTextColor(hdc,RGB(25,250,250));
POINT p[3];   
p[1].x=280;
p[1].y=280;
p[2].x=280;
p[2].y=290;
p[3].x=285;
p[3].y=285;
Polygon(hdc,p,3);
TextOut(hdc,10,10,"hhhhh",5);
```

But when I run it, only shows a white rectangle into the parent window, neither the rect is filled with black brush, nor there is any text in it.

Could you guys tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: You do not seem to understand, how a Windows Desktop application operates. See [Walkthrough: Creating Windows Desktop Applications (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx) for a quick introduction. This is not a replacement for real learning material. Consider getting a copy of Jeffrey Richter's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition (Developer Reference)](http://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X).

Comment: Also you have resource leak and `p[3].x` is invalid

Comment: @BarmakShemirani that's not a resource leak; that's invalid indexing result in a buffer overrun. There is a resource leak in that the brush is not destroyed.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: @BarmakShemirani oh, I misread the "and" as a colon; silly me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to display animations, you should never try to directly write to a window that way, because many events could cause the window to redraw itself erasing what you have just written.

The correct way is to put it in the WM_PAINT handler.

Comment: Thanks, it now shows the text. But not the triangle. Could suggest what should I do for drawing a triangle?

Comment: You forgot to select the brush created by `CreateSolidBrush()` into the DC. See [`SelectObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

A few issues, in addition to not using `WM_PAINT`.

First, merely calling `CreateSolidBrush()` is not enough to mark that brush as the one for your drawing operations to use. You have to select the brush into a DC ([device context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183553.aspx)) before you can use it. This is done with the [`SelectObject()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). General usage looks like

```
HBRUSH prevBrush;

prevBrush = SelectObject(hdc, newBrush);
// drawing functions
SelectObject(hdc, prevBrush);
```

Yes, it is important to restore the previous brush when finished, even on a fresh DC; the initial state must be restored. The initial state uses a brush that draws nothing; this is why your `Polygon()` doesn't draw anything. `SelectObject()` is used for all the various things you use to draw with (pens, fonts, etc.), not just brushes.

Second, in C array indices start at 0 and go to `size - 1`, not start at 1 and go to `size`. So instead of saying `pt[1]`, `pt[2]`, and `pt[3]`, you say `pt[0]`, `pt[1]`, and `pt[2]`. Your compiler should have warned you about this.

Third, [as the documentation for `CreateSolidBrush()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will have said, once you are finished with the brush you must destroy it with `DeleteObject()`. You must do this *after* selecting the previous brush back in. You must also do this with the brush you used in the `FillRect()` call.

Comment: Typo: It should be `DeleteObject` instead of `DestroyObject`